# Possible to add css styles to specific component buttons?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add a white outline via css box-shadow, but whenever I click on any of the buttons, they all get the outline instead of just the actual button I clicked.

Is there a way so only the button component I click on gets the outline and then toggles off if I click it again?

Here is my current code:

```
const [selectState, setSelectState] = useState(false);

const Button = ({ selected, text }) => {
  function handleClick() {
    setSelectState(true);
  }

  return (
    <span
      onClick={handleClick}
      className={`btn-style ${selected ? "selected" : ""}`}
    >
      {text}
    </span>
  );
};

export default function Hello() {
  return (
    <Button selected={selectState} text='Blue'/>
    <Button selected={selectState} text='Red'/>
    <Button selected={selectState} text='Green'/>
  );
}
```

**.selected css:**

```
.selected {
  box-shadow: rgb(17 206 101) 0px 0px 0px 2px inset !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to track the selected state of individual elements, you'd need to handle the onClick method and make corresponding state change in parent element.

```
const Button = ({ selected, text, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <span
      onClick={onClick}
      className={`btn-style ${selected ? "selected" : ""}`}
    >
      {text}
    </span>
  );
};

export default function Hello() {
  const [selectState, setSelectState] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Button
        onClick={() => setSelectState(1)}
        selected={selectState === 1}
        text="Blue"
      />
      <Button
        onClick={() => setSelectState(2)}
        selected={selectState === 2}
        text="Red"
      />
      <Button
        onClick={() => setSelectState(3)}
        selected={selectState === 3}
        text="Green"
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the click handler tell the parent component to save the clicked button index in state, and pass that state down to determine whether the `selected` class is needed:

```
const Button = ({ selected, text, onClick }) => {

    return (
        <span
            onClick={onClick}
            className={`btn-style ${selected ? "selected" : ""}`}
        >
            {text}
        </span>
    );
};

export default function Hello({ texts }) {
    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(-1);
    return (<>
        {
            texts.map((text, i) => <Button selected={i === selectedIndex} text={text} onClick={() => setSelectedIndex(i)}} />)
        }
    </>);
}
ReactDOM.render(<Hello texts={['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']} />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```